# Magento 1.9+ Paypal NVP API Logic Flow

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community, paypal-express, nvp-gateway-error

I've recently began building a community module that allows Magento to react appropriately when certain PayPal error codes are returned from the `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` call.

However with Magento 1.9+ I'm seeing there's an oddity.  Looking at line 524 on `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Api/Nvp.php`, we can see that there is a new array element added as follows:

```
protected $_requiredResponseParams = array(
    self::DO_DIRECT_PAYMENT             => array('ACK', 'CORRELATIONID', 'AMT'),
    self::DO_EXPRESS_CHECKOUT_PAYMENT   => array('ACK', 'CORRELATIONID', 'AMT'), // this line was added
);
```

The second array element is not present in Magento 1.8 and prior.  This addition causes Magento 1.9+ to throw an exception earlier in the error handler than in past versions.

```
public function call($methodName, array $request)
{

    /// code above snipped

    if (!$this->_validateResponse($methodName, $response)) { /// THIS CALL THROWS IN MAGENTO 1.9+
        Mage::logException(new Exception(
            Mage::helper('paypal')->__("PayPal response hasn't required fields.")
        ));
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('paypal')->__('There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later.'));
    }

    $this->_callErrors = array();
    if ($this->_isCallSuccessful($response)) {
        if ($this->_rawResponseNeeded) {
            $this->setRawSuccessResponseData($response);
        }
        return $response;
    }
    $this->_handleCallErrors($response); /// Execution reaches here in Magento 1.8 and prior
    return $response;
}
```

According to the PayPal documentation, the following error codes should result in the user being redirected back to PayPal from the application:

- 10417
- 10422
- 10485
- 10486
- 10736

In Magento 1.9+, the execution never reaches the point where an override of `_handleCallErrors` is able to properly figure out if a redirect is required or not.

**Was there a good reason for this change, or just an oversight?  Should I be concerned about removing the second array element of the `_requiredResponseParams` in the overriding class?**

-Edit 1
It looks like there's a non-fatal error handling mechanism built into Magento 1.9+, however the presense of the addition to the `_requiredResponseParams` array is preventing the code from executing.

Interesting...

Comment: Link to the extension on GitHub: https://github.com/thinklikeamage/Stabilis_PaypalExpressRedirect

Comment: Did you fix this? What is the resolution? Would be great of you can share ti